# Write to multiple text files from CSV data

Tags: python

So I have created a program to take data from a .csv file and export it into a format that I can use on a self build wiki.

So the code obviously loops every time a new line is added.

I want when it loops it must write the data into a new .txt file with a name that it got from the .txt file. Please assist in doing so

So I have tried defining the whole code as a veritable and export it, but I am really not familiar with Python and I would appreciate your help...

```
import csv

with open('123.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'========{row[7]} - {row[1]}========')
            line_count += 1
        #Info
            print(f'===General Info===')
            line_count += 1
            print(f'Coordinates: {row[5]}  {row[10]}')
            line_count += 1
        if row[8] == 'n':
            print(f'Eskom Site')
        else:
            print(f'Solar Site')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Input .csv file

```
No,Site,Rek Nr,Naam ,Nommer,Coordinates,Sectors,No,Solar Site,Camera,,Monitor Address
1,Nedbank,,,,1,35,128,n,,\\,n
2,Silicon,,,,2,16,129,n,,\\,n
3,Twilight,,,,3,17,130,n,,\\,n
4,Percy,,,,4,20,131,n,,\\,n
5,Rey,,,,5,13,132,n,,\\,n
```

Output:

```
========128 - Nedbank========
===General Info===
Coordinates: 1  \\
Eskom Site
========129 - Silicon========
===General Info===
Coordinates: 2  \\
Eskom Site
========130 - Twilight========
===General Info===
Coordinates: 3  \\
Eskom Site
========131 - Percy========
===General Info===
Coordinates: 4  \\
Eskom Site
========132 - Rey========
===General Info===
Coordinates: 5  \\
Eskom Site
```

So every time a line starts at ========x - x======== it must write it to a new txt file

Comment: Do you want to write all the `print` statements in a .txt file? It would be better if you give sample input and your expected output in the separate file as it's not clear from your program what you're expecting.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: It isn't very clear where you want to get the name of the output file from and what you want to print to it.

Comment: @StefanMostert: Your question is not clear enough. How is the data structured in the CSV file? Do you have a file name in each row of a certain column? And want the corresponding row to go into a new CSV file, which you would save with the file name you got from that row of the first CSV file? Give a dummy (small) dataset as an example.

Comment: @CypherX It must create new .txt file every time a new line starts in the.csv file

Comment: Provide sample input and expected out put of your program.

Comment: @StefanMostert: Ok. So, let's say that you have 10 lines in there already. And now you add the 11th line (which is I guess something similar to the example data you pasted in the comment section). You would want to create a new `.txt` file for this 11th line alone? Or, do you want to create a file that includes all the 11 lines of data?

Comment: what does this statement mean - `into a new .txt file with a name that it got from the .txt file.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code to write the print statements to a `.txt` file. **Note**: This will write all the contents to a single file.

```
import csv

with open('123.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open("xyz.txt", "w") as txt_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            txt_file.write('Column names are { %s }\n'%(','.join(row)))
        else:
            txt_file.write('========{} - {}========\n'.format(row[7], row[1]))
        #Info
            txt_file.write('===General Info===\n')
            txt_file.write('Coordinates: {}  {}\n'.format(row[5], row[10]))
        if row[8] == 'n':
            txt_file.write('Eskom Site\n')
        else:
            txt_file.write('Solar Site\n')
        line_count += 1
    txt_file.write('Processed {} lines.\n'.format(str(line_count)))
```

But if you want each line of the `.csv` file, which is a bit incomprehensible why!, to be written to a separate file, you can just tweak the above program to do that-

```
import csv

with open('123.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        new_file_name = row[8] + ' - ' + row[4]
        with open(new_file_name, 'a+') as txt_file:
            if line_count == 0:
                txt_file.write('Column names are { %s }\n'%(','.join(row)))
            else:
                txt_file.write('========{} - {}========\n'.format(row[7], row[1]))
                #Info
                txt_file.write('===General Info===\n')
                txt_file.write('Coordinates: {}  {}\n'.format(row[5], row[10]))
            if row[8] == 'n':
                txt_file.write('Eskom Site\n')
            else:
                txt_file.write('Solar Site\n')
            line_count += 1
        #txt_file.write('Processed {} lines.\n'.format(str(line_count)))
```

Which file do you want to write the last statement after processing all the lines- `Processed {} lines`? If you want to write this to another file, you can do this-

```
last_file_name = str(line_count)
with open(last_file_name, 'w') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write('Processed {} lines.\n'.format(str(line_count)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although I get this error


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open('123.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open("xyz.txt", "w") as txt_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '123.csv'

Comment: @StefanMostert You are getting that error because file `123.csv` is not in the same directory where you are executing the script from. See the second part of the answer which will write each line to a different file named after the line-numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I want! 

Now the last thing can I change it that it export to a custom name that it gets the data from the .csv file? Like the name will be row[8] - row[4].txt

Comment: @StefanMostert Made the changes to use the filename as `row[8] - row[4].txt` and changed the mode to append `a+` as some of the lines may have the same value of `row[8] - row[4].txt` to avoid earlier lines being overwritten in the same file.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer so that similar questions in future can refer to this answer!